# Options for small background tasks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, android-asynctask

I have a static method that does a network "heavy" call let's call this `getDataFromCloudServer()`. Now a new handly utility method will be composed that will have this method.
Example:

```
public static void periodicUpdate(Context ctx) {  
    clearCachedData();  
    List<Object> newData = getDataFromCloudServer(ctx);  
    persist(newData);  
}
```

This new handy method would need to be trigger when an event on the UI thread occurs. But obviously I can't call it from UI thread.
So wanting to avoid having small anonymous AsyncTasks to the callers I thought of:

```
public static void periodicUpdateInAsyncTask(final Context ctx) {  
   AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> updaterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {   
       @Override    
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
            periodicUpdate(ctx);  
       }  
    };
    updaterTask.execute();  
}
```

My concern is if this is a good idea. Basically I think the AsyncTask is not "controlled"/cancelled etc.
What are the issues here and how can I write this correctly?

Comment: The documentation of AsyncTask says that you should not use it to run tasks that takes more than 2 seconds which then rules out network heavy calls. The documentation further suggests using ExecutorService or FutureTask. The way I see it you can construct a FutureTask and pss it to ExecutorService. When you need to cancel it, you can just call cancel on the Future object that you hold. AsyncTask is not cut out for this.

Comment: So what is the most appropriate construct for my use case? A service?

Comment: The reason not to use it for long tasks is that by default all AsyncTasks launch on the same thread.  So if you don't explicitly launch it on its own thread via executeOnExecutor, you'll hold up all future AsyncTasks

Comment: @GabeSechan:Ah I see. Actually I don't expect the network call to take more than 5 secs at max

Comment: 5s isn't much of a problem, especially if you don't have other tasks queue up.  I would in general put a timeout on any socket or http call in an AsyncTask.

Comment: @GabeSechan:I can't really put a timeout to skip the refresh though. Is there a way to code this properly then?

Comment: @Jim - it is more apt to use a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor() and pass it a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html which wraps the periodicUpdate method in its Callable

Comment: @Jim Sure you can.  You have to worry about timeouts anyway-  if you can't reach the server, you can't update the data.  If this is just a standard http request, the default timeout is probably fine and your approach is fine.  The biggest problem is that the task will hold on to the Context until finished which causes the Context and all memory used by it not to be released until then, but that's a problem no matter where you launch it from.

Comment: @user3493289 Umm, cancel is built into AsyncTask and has been since ANdroid v1.  What he's doing is pretty bog standard except for doing it in a static function, so I'm not sure what your point is here.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the AsyncTask is not "controlled"/cancelled etc.

Actually, it's up to a developer of AsyncTask to adhere cancel state.

AsyncTask tied to the lifecycle of its process. So you may have some problems like memory leaks (which you solved by static declaration), but keep in mind that with background process you are low in the [priority list for killing](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). If you are not Ok with that use Services.

If you want to be tied to the lifecycle of Activity use AsyncTaskLoader.

If you are not planning to publish results in the UI Thread you can use standard java threads.

For network stuff with caching results in a DB I would use Services.